# When a record is submitted for approval, how to display a picklist field value other than its default value?

Tags: approval-process, record-type

There is an object (OSR), when a record is created and is submitted for approval, status field(picklist) value changes from 'Not Submitted'(default value in the record type) to 'Open'. If we try to edit that record, we can see the default value('Not Submitted') and 'Open' but I want to see one more picklist value -- 'In progress'.
Can it be done using apex class ?
If yes, then what will be the logic as I am confused because it is related to the event that is taking place after the approval button is clicked.

[image]

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done if we have 2 record types assigned to the different profiles and the user profile who is submitting the record for approval and the user profile who is accepting/rejecting the record should be different.